# Is it possible to check file exists with out file connection?

Tags: java, file

In my project, I attach a file using `File f = new File(filePath);` and then check the existing file using `f.exists()`. So my question is: Is it possible to check the existence of a file without `File f = new File(filePath);`? It's just that as far as I understand in Java, if there is a file, then it binds, and if not, then it creates a new one. I just don't want to overwrite a file that may contain important data.

Comment: Nothing is bound. You have an instance of java's `File` class which does not interact with the file system unless you instruct it to do that. If it would automatically create the file, `f.exists()` wouldn't make sense. Have you read the documentation of the `File` class?

Comment: *"It's just that as far as I understand in Java, if there is a file, then it binds, and if not, then it creates a new one."* Where are you getting this from? Did you try it out?

Comment: I must have misunderstood ur question but `new File(filePath)` doesn't create a file, `new File(filePath).createNewFile()` does

Comment: No , not for practical purpose , the only alternate is java.nio.files.File and java.nio.files.Path but is in fact more complex. Also , new File(path) DOES NOT create a file , java.io.File has a boolean method you must call to create the file.

Answer (score 1):

> It's just that as far as I understand in Java, if there is a file, then it binds, and if not, then it creates a new one.

No, and no.

File is incredibly lightweight. It wraps around a string. **That is all it does**. `new File("whatever")` makes zero calls to the underlying OS, opens no file handles, and in fact is entirely a memory operation, and would work fine even if your disk is failing as we speak.

Memory and CPU and OS call wise there is no difference whatsoever between `new File("foo")` and `String x = "foo"`. Except, I guess, for an extremely lightweight object that contains just 1 reference (to a string containing the path).

`new File("someRealFile.txt")` does not open the file; it wouldn't cause that file to be created if it doesn't exist, and it does not cause that file, if it exists, to now be un-deletable on OSes that make it impossible to delete files that are open, such as windows.

Hence, `new File("someFile.txt").exists()` is it - that is as light weight as you want it to be.

There *is* a new file API: `java.nio.file`. It would look like:

```
Files.exists(Path.of("/path/to/file"))
```

The reason to use it have nothing to do with 'binding'. the new API has two features:

- The old API uses return values for errors. For example, `new File("something.txt").mkdir()`, if it fails, it just returns `false`. This is bad design - it's un-java-like (very few other java libraries do this), and that makes the problem with that design even more problematic - because the problem is that you're likely to forget to check. In contrast to exceptions (the mechanism used by the new file APIs). With exceptions, if you forget to deal with them, you'll know at runtime, vs a 'silently, nothing happens' that results in hours-long bug hunts. Also, booleans offer no info; exceptions have properties and string based messages to look at.
- The new file API offers more features. You can use it to fetch file creation timestamps for example, or to follow softlinks. Things the old API cannot do.

If those are relevant to your case you might want to switch, or you want to switch to the newer API simply for consistency. But you don't have to do it to address this non-existent 'binding / creation' problem.

Answer (score -1):

You can use a newer `Path` class, which is [well](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/check.html) [covered](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/pathOps.html) in the official tutorial.

```java
Path path = Paths.get(filePath);

if (!Files.exists(path)) {
    System.out.println("The file doesn't exist");
}
```

The `Path` class serves mostly the same purpose as the old `File` class, but includes more functionality and less confusingly named.

On a side note, I never could get why people devote so much attention to checking the file's existence. Usually you don't just check but do something else with the file. And what if the file gets gone in the time between the check and the usage? Just handle the appropriate `IOException`, you'll have to do it in the commercial code anyway.

Comment: This is a misleading answer. By talking about `Path` it very strongly insinuates that OP is correct (that `new File()` 'binds'). But OP isn't correct. Misleading answers deserve downvotes.

Comment: On the contrary, I answered precisely what was asked. As for the OP's misconceptions, they are numerous, not unique, inevitable and thus very much excusable. I'm not interested in any of them very much, I just concentrate on the task at hand, which is, checking for file existence in Java in 2023.